# merge excel file data with windows azure

Tags: sql, excel, azure

Hello friends, I just want to know, how to merge Excel file with windows Azure sql database file ?

I have uploaded main data to azure sql database, and I want to append my daily work from excel sheet to azure main uploaded database.

Is there a way to append data easily with azure database?

Please guide or let me know the way.

I am trying to use this one:

Managing Master Data with MDS and Microsoft Excel

```
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/DBI204
```

but it's unable to connect.

Answer (score 0):

i have found my way through it thanks anyways.

i just achieved my goal with help of Visual studio data tools.

;)

much easy and convenient.